# Positioned divs spilling out of container

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I'm trying to use [this](http://github.com/heyadem/stackgrid.adem.js) jquery grid plugin, but it's not working with my layout. The images are stacked on top of each other, they seem to be spilling out of .main, and they overlap the footer. Help? :C

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 color:      $fontcolor;
 background-color: #eee;
 font: 100% 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 background-color:      $main-bg;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
}

.main {
 width: 100%;
 background-color:     $content-bg;
 
}

.grid-container {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative; }

.grid-item {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
 }

.grid-item img {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 100%; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
    <div class='grid-container'>
     <div class='grid-item'>
      <img alt='' src='stackgrid/example/img/short.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class='grid-item'>
      <img alt='' src='stackgrid/example/img/tall.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class='grid-item'>
      <img alt='' src='stackgrid/example/img/medium.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class='grid-item'>
      <img alt='' src='stackgrid/example/img/tall.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class='grid-item'>
      <img alt='' src='stackgrid/example/img/short.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class='grid-item'>
      <img alt='' src='stackgrid/example/img/medium.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class='grid-item'>
      <img alt='' src='stackgrid/example/img/medium.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class='grid-item'>
      <img alt='' src='stackgrid/example/img/short.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class='grid-item'>
      <img alt='' src='stackgrid/example/img/medium.jpg'>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: need more detail..... only css wont help us to figure this

Comment: Seems unlikely that a grid system would use `position:absolute`...I'd start there.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are initializing stackgrid in `window` `load`.

Also try the `.reset()` method.